# Get Average from Polymorphic Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am both trying to get the review counts and the average review ratings.

I have tables:

Tables:

- id
- .....

Chairs:

- id
- .....

Reviews:

- id
- rating
- reviewable_id
- reviewable_type

```
class Review extends Model {
    public function reviewable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}

class Tables extends Model {
    public function reviews() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Review', 'reviewable');
    }

    public function avg_rating() {
        return $this->reviews()
            ->selectRaw('avg(rating) as avgRating, review_id')
            ->groupBy('review_id');
    }

}
```

I've tried:

```php
Table::with(['avg_rating'])->withCount('reviews')->where(function($q) use ($regex_terms, $terms){
   $q->where('name', 'REGEXP', $regex_terms);
})->get();
```

But get "Unknown column 'review_id' in 'field list'" or attempting it with variations of "hasmany" yielded only an empty array or an array with the reviews. Just wonder what the best way to accomplish this is or if I'd have to loop through the reviews and calculate manually or a second raw query

I have this but not sure if it is efficient or best practice within Eloquent:

```
$tables->each(function ($table) {
    $table->review_average = DB::table('reviews')
    ->select(DB::raw("ROUND( avg(rating), 2) as avg"))
    ->where("reviewable_id", "=", $table->id)->first()->avg;
});
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates

Comment: have you tried ```withAvg``` method ?

Comment: @ManojKiran Thanks! That put me on the right path. Apparently, I was using Lumen based on the Laravel 6 framework, so it had been throwing a "method not found" error when I tried it before. But after searching for that method, I saw that it was a higher version Laravel function. So, updating to Laravel/Lumen 8 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was using Lumen based on the Laravel 6 framework, so it had been throwing a "method not found" error when I tried "withAvg" before. But after searching for that method, I saw that it required a higher version of Laravel. So, updating to Laravel/Lumen 8 allowed me to use the "withAvg" function.

So now my query builder statement looks like:

```
Table::with(['avg_rating'])->withCount('reviews')->withAvg("reviews", "rating")->where(function($q) use ($regex_terms, $terms){
   $q->where('name', 'REGEXP', $regex_terms);
})->get();
```